# Retrieving the images from database and displaying in view

Tags: php, opencart

How to retrieve the images if there are multiple images in a single row. I am using this below code to get the images. if there is single image it is displaying. But, I need to display multiple images.

Here is my code:

```
<?php if(!empty($img['image'])) { ?>  
    <img src="<?php echo $img['image'];?>" width="100px" height="50px"/>
<?php }else {?>
    <img src="image/data/photo/profile1.png" width="100px" height="50px"/>
<?php }?>
```

I used this function in view for displaying the images

Comment: And how does a string / row look with multiple images in it? - Also, have you tried something yourself?

Comment: It will be inserted into database by separating through commas

Comment: Have a look at `explode();`

Comment: i didnt get what u are saying explode is used to separate a string right

Comment: Yes, explode is used to separate a string into an' array by a delimiter, that way you can access each image individually and use a loop to print/show them all.

Comment: Yes use explode() function,First you need to get your images from database,then use explode() and then iterate it with loop

Comment: Iam not getting how to do

Comment: can u please help me iam new to  php

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

    if(!empty($img['image'])) { 

        $images = explode($img['image'],','); 
        foreach($images as $image) 
        { 
            print '<img src="' . $image . '" width="100px" height="50px"/>'; 
        } 
    }else {
        print '<img src="image/data/boutique/profile1.png" width="100px" height="50px"/>';
    }

?>
```

or

```
<?php 

    if(!empty($img['image'])) { 

        $images = explode($img['image'],','); 
        foreach($images as $image) 
        {
            ?>
            <img src="<?php print $image ?>" width="100px" height="50px"/>
            <?php
        } 
    }else {
        ?>
        <img src="image/data/boutique/profile1.png" width="100px" height="50px"/>
        <?php
    }

?>
```

Comment: <?php if(!empty($cuss['image'])) { ?> 
             $images = explode($img['image'],',');
              foreach($images as $image)
    {
        print '<img src="' . $image . '" width="100px" height="50px"/>';
    }          
      <img src="<?php echo $cuss['image'];?>" width="100px" height="50px"/>
      <?php }else {?>
      <img src="image/data/boutique/profile1.png" width="100px" height="50px"/>
      <?php }?>

Comment: Your close its the tags you got mixed up on, I will edit my post with the code but try looking over at www.w3schools.com php section it may help you get started :)

Comment: The code which i has posted first in that code can u edit please

Comment: That's what I have done, this will work as you requested....you had extra code and tags that are not needed.

Comment: no it is not working which u edited not getting the images

Comment: in the post at the top you have used $img['image'] but in your comment you have gone for $cuss['image'] -  you need to make sure you are using the correct one